# How to replace sections of non-org files from within org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, python, tangle

I am trying to write some notes on django with the help of org babel.
Is there a way to replace a block in a file(which was not tangled with org) after I eval a certain src block?

Here's what I mean:

If my project is named ProjectA, django automatically creates the following files:

```
Project A
├── asgi.py
├── __init__.py
├── settings.py
├── urls.py
└── wsgi.py
```

Now, from within org-mode, I am creating a new app called `core` by executing the following:

```
#+begin_src shell
python manage.py startapp core
  #+end_src
```

It creates a new directory called "core" with some boilerplate files.

There is a section inside `ProjA/settings.py` where all manually created app should be registered explicitly:

```
  INSTALLED_APPS = [
      'django.contrib.admin',
      'django.contrib.auth',
      'django.contrib.contenttypes',
      'django.contrib.sessions',
      'django.contrib.messages',
      'django.contrib.staticfiles',
      'core',
  ]
```

Right now, I manually appended `core` to the end of the `INSTALLED_APPS`.
But since I am creating the app from within org-babel, is there a way to register the app from within org-mode without manually going to settings.py(which is not an org tangled file) and appending `core` to the end?
Thanks.

Comment: One way might be to write a `#begin_src python` block that imports the `settings` python module and appends `core` to the list `INSTALLED_APPS`. Regular python import issues apply, so you may need to use the `:dir` org header arg to run the python code from the correct directory.